# llvm on x86 barebone?

Tags: operating-system, llvm

Does anyone know of any project involving running LLVm without an OS, i.e. directly on x86 hardware?

Comment: It's hard to see how that would work as you would need at least a file system, memory management, runtime libraries and bootstrap code to support a compiler on any given hardware platform. At that point you have the bare bones of a minimal operating system anyway. What is it that you're trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @Paul: write an OS on top of LLVM. I'm not asking for the entire LLVM toolchain to be on a barebone x86. I'm only asking for the LLVM runtime (with it's JIT) to be on a barebone x86.

Comment: so which part of LLVM exactly do you want to run barebone? The interpreter? JIT? Compiler? Or are you asking if you can run LLVM-compiled native code without an OS?

Answer (score 7):

LLVM can statically compile code which can run directly on x86 hardware. However, the LLVM JIT relies on most of the LLVM libraries. It is not possible to compile these for a bare-bones x86 target.

In order to base an OS on LLVM IR and have it be JITed I see two options:

1. Write a new JIT engine designed to be run directly on x86 hardware. This would require re-writing all of the optimization passes if you wanted it to have any benefit over static compilation.
2. Take the smallest kernel you can that is easy to target LLVM for, then run the JIT on that. This means that the core of your OS won't be JITed, but a large part of it could be.